# How to find the path of sqlite.sql file and print it?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, swift3

I know this question already answered before but when I tried to print the path for the sqlite file of my application as below I got the path but could not go to it in finder.
I used below code to get the path

```
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String
    print(paths)
```

The path I got is as below:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5412CDDE-8D40-46B2-A61D-65065796F7CE/Documents

when I try to copy and paste it in GOTO it can not find it

please advise me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access files in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application without jailbreaking iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064042/access-files-in-var-mobile-containers-data-application-without-jailbreaking-iph)

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using `NSPersistantContainer`, you get the URL(s):

```
persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first!.url!
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to copy and paste it in GOTO it can not find it

that path is on the Simulator and not on the local Finder.

Duplicate of: [Access files in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application without jailbreaking iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064042/access-files-in-var-mobile-containers-data-application-without-jailbreaking-iph)

or

Duplicate of: [How to view the data in sqlite file running in iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644158/how-to-view-the-data-in-sqlite-file-running-in-iphone-application/4644189#4644189)

> How to find the path of sqlite.sql file and print it?

accessing your sqlite database is described here:

[Copy Sqlite DataBase in Swift does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563708/copy-sqlite-database-in-swift-does-not-work-properly)

Comment: so how can I know the path for the sqllite file?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your swift class to get the location of sqlite database for your application running in iOS simulator.

```
let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
print(urls[urls.count-1] as URL)
```

You will need SQLite database browser to look after the database. We can only locate sqlite database file only for application running in simulator but not in the iPhone directly.